# 'I have decided to purchase a jet for getting to NYC and back more quickly.'

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitive-vs-gerund, verbal-noun

Are the following sentences grammatical or not? If not, does substituting a *to-infinite* make them grammatical? (Optional: designate if the sentence expresses purpose, reason, aim, or function)

> 1 I have decided to purchase a jet *for getting* to NYC and back more quickly.
>
> 2 I have decided to buy a jet *for having* a quicker way to get to NYC and back.

This is my only reason and aim; this will be the jet's only purpose and function.

> 3 I hate hairdryers, so I am buying a space heater *for drying my hair* more naturally, and that is my only aim & purpose & reason and that will be its only function
>
> 4 *For having* a lasting shine in your hair, buy ShineOn Shampoo.
>
> 5 My neighbor and I have decided to cooperate more *for having* a better life together.

---

*Research done:*

ELL [How can I decide when to use “for” + “-ing” or “to” + [infinitive] in a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24553/how-can-i-decide-when-to-use-for-ing-or-to-infinitive-in-a-sentence)

(Note the [accepted answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24890/6951) here is a restatement of Cambridge Dictionary's [For + -ing or to + infinitive?](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/for-ing))

ELL [Expressing a purpose with for + gerund?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11057/expressing-a-purpose-with-for-gerund)

ELL [Can “for -ing” form be used after a noun to indicate the purpose of the noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37638/can-for-ing-form-be-used-after-a-noun-to-indicate-the-purpose-of-the-noun)

BBC English [To + infinitive and for + verb-ing to express purpose](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv284.shtml) (Currently the best site I've found.)

ELU [Clauses of purpose: “for + -ing” or "to-infinitive [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204442/clauses-of-purpose-for-ing-or-to-infinitive)

All of which have answers that I find  (i) incomplete (ii) contradictory (iii) terribly confusing, if not (iv) wrong. To sort through the haze, I am focusing on one issue.

*Background*

Some sources say that you need to use a to-infinitive for expressing *purpose*, *aim*, *function*, *reason*, *etc*. I find these to be rather hazy distinctions, given that the ODO defines *[purpose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/purpose)* as *The reason for which something is done or created or for which something exists* and the same work lists as [synonyms for *purpose*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english-thesaurus/purpose): *aim*, *reason*, *function*, *etc*.

It is my assertion that at least some of the following sentences demonstrate that one can use the *-ing form* (be it a gerund, verbal noun, participle) to express individual purpose (aim, reason, function, intention, whatever you want to call it). Do you agree, or not? Why (not)?

---

**In shorter terms, are the sentences grammatical?** or do we have to substitute a *to-infinitive* (including *in order to + infinitive*) to make them grammatical? (Optional: designate if the sentence expresses purpose, reason, aim, function, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

We can use both constructions to express purpose - ***to-infinitive*** and ***for+verb-ing***.

In answer to the question asking **"WHY"**, a *to-infinitive* is often used. On the other hand, in answer to the question asking **"WHAT FOR"**, we use *for+verb-ing* or *for+noun*.

This is not very helpful as both the questions mean more or less the same thing.

**From Practical English Usage (PEU) by Michael Swan -**

> **213 FOR: Purpose and Cause**
>
> **1. People's purposes**
>
> *For* can be used to talk about somebody's purpose in doing something, but only when it's followed by a noun.
>
> > > He stopped at the pub **for a drink**. 
> > >       I went to the college **for an interview** with Professor Taylor.
>
> *For* is not used before a verb in this sense. The infinitive alone is used to express a person's purpose.
>
> > > We stopped at the pub **to have a drink**. (**NOT** ...<s>**for having** a drink</s>.) 
> > >       I went to the college **to see Professor Taylor**. (**NOT** ...<s>**for seeing** Professor Taylor</s>.)
>
> **2. The purposes of things: *-ing* forms and infinitives**
>
> *For* can be used before the *-ing* form of a verb to express the 'purpose' of a thing - what it's used for - especially when the thing
>   is the subject of the clause.
>
> > > Is that cake **for eating** or just **for looking at**? 
> > >       An altimeter is used **for measuring** height above sea level.
>
> When the clause has a person as subject, it is more common to use an
>   infinitive to express the purpose of a thing.
>
> > > **We** use altimeter **to measure** height above sea level.
>
> **3. Causes of reactions**
>
> *For...ing* can also be used after a description of a positive or negative reaction, to explain the behaviour that caused it.
>
> > > We are grateful to you **for helping** us out. 
> > >       I'm angry with you **for waking** me up. 
> > >       They punished the child **for lying**. 
> > >       He was sent to prison **for stealing**.

Apart from that there are verbs that collocate well with one construction over the other. It depends on individual verbs. 

 For example - The verb **need** prefers infinitive construction, and using *for+verb-ing* is considered incorrect.

> I need **to get** some sleep. (**NOT** ...<s>**for getting** some sleep</s>)

But

> I need glasses **for reading**. 
>   I need time **to study**. 
>   The men need courage **to confront** the obstacles in their lives.

> I need you **to help** me with cooking. (*you are helping me in cooking*.) 
>   I need Sam **to complete** the mission. (**NOT** ...<s>**for completing** the mission</s>) [**REASON?** Refer to point #2 from the quotation from PEU]

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Now coming to the sentences you quoted.

> <sub>?</sub> **1.** I have decided to purchase a jet for getting to NYC and back more quickly.

The verb **decide** takes infinitive construction. So this is correct - *I have decided to purchase a jet*. 
Now after that the sentence adds why *I* have decided to purchase the jet. There is not preference of infinitive construction or *for+verb-ing* construction after the verb **purchase**, so we can use either one of them. Now checking from the PEU quotation, we can find out that infinitive construction is preferred because the purchase is carried out by a human.

> I have decided to purchase a jet **to get** to NYC and back more quickly.

Your second sentence  -

> <sub>?</sub> **2.**  I have decided to buy a jet for having a quicker way to get to NYC and back.

The verb **decide** takes infinitive construction. So this is correct - *I have decided to buy a jet*. 
Now after that the sentence adds why *I* have decided to purchase the jet. There is not preference of infinitive construction or *for+verb-ing* construction after the verb **buy**, so we can use either one of them. Now checking from the PEU quotation, we can find out that infinitive construction is preferred because the purchase is carried out by a human.

> I have decided to buy a jet **to have** a quicker way to get to NYC and back.

Your third sentence  -

> <sub>?</sub> **3.** I hate hairdryers, so I am buying a space heater for drying my hair more naturally.

As already mentioned there is no preference from these two constructions after the verb **buy**, we can use either one of them. But as the quotation from PEU (point  #2) mentions for person's purpose infinitive construction is preferred, infinitive construction is preferred here. It's *I* who is buying the drier for some purpose. It's *I*'s purpose.

> I hate hairdryers, so I am buying a space heater **to buy** my hair more naturally.

Your fourth sentence  -

> <sub>?</sub> **4.** For having a lasting shine in your hair, buy ShineOn Shampoo.

As already mentioned there is no preference from these two constructions after the verb **buy**, we can use either one of them. But as the quotation from PEU (point  #2) mentions for person's purpose infinitive construction is preferred, infinitive construction is preferred here. It's *you* who is buying the drier for some purpose. It's *you*'s purpose.

Your fifth sentence -

> <sub>?</sub> **5.** My neighbor and I have decided to cooperate more for having a better life together.

After the verb **decide** infinitive construction is preferred. So it's correct - *My neighbour and I have decided to cooperate more.* 
Now after that the sentence adds the information why they decided to do that. So we have two options open. We can use either one of them. From point #2 (quotation from PEU), we came to know if it's a person's purpose infinitive construction is preferred. Therefore in this sentence infinitive construction is preferred. *My neighbour and I* cooperated, and we have some purpose.

> My neighbor and I have decided to cooperate more **to have** a better life together.

Comment: So, per PEU, you would change all of them from *for -ing* to *to infinitive*? I could see this, especially if the sentences are expressing *purpose*. But what if we do not want to express the subject I's purpose/reason/aim/etc, but we want to express the *function* of the thing purchased? Can we still not say *for + -ing*? Ex *I bought a new shelf displaying my DVDs.* (Which seems to take us back to Sentence 1.) I like your answer. I am not entirely convinced.

Comment: @pazzo Thanks. I don't know if not following what PEU recommended it's ungrammatical or not, because PEU itself said that "**it's more common**". So from there we can draw some conclusion: that in some cases (cases like your example sentences) are not ungrammatical, but may be they are less common. The first sentence in Cambridge uses **for**  construction even when the subject is a human. That is similar to your first sentence. *I need something for storing CDs.* - The purpose of something is *store CDs*, and something is definitely not human, (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) so it's justified that **for** construction is used. But if we see it from the point of view of the subject **to** construction is preferred. So it's basically a choice, as far as I see it. That's why in COCA there are few hits for **soap for washing** compared to **soap to wash**. The only purpose of soap is washing, so both construction can be okay. But in your sentence #1, though I still believe it's also acceptable, it's like this *He purchased X* X -> a NP -> a Jet for traveling. **For** construction is possible. At the same time **to** construction is also possible. (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) but when you specify the destination and starting point of the jet, it's a bit unusual. I mean the Jet can travel even beyond that. So in that particular case it's not wise to see from the *jet's* perspective. Because Jet can travel anywhere. So it's better to see from the human subject's perspective. (I don't know if these comments does at all make sense, but that is what I think. I didn't find any other reference about this topic.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I agree that sometimes you can use the -ing form.  Sometimes, that's the most natural way to do it.

- I bought a spray nozzle for *washing my car*.
- I have decided to  buy a jet for *getting to NYC*...

However, sometimes it's not so natural:

- I have decided to buy a jet for *having* [X]

This would flow much better as

- I have decided to buy a jet, {*to have / so I will have*} [X]

This might be because "have" is much less active than "wash". The nozzle could be thought of helping you to wash, but the jet will not "have" a faster way to get to and fro—YOU will! And you will "have" the jet as well. It's not about what the jet does, it's about why YOU *buy* it. That is, the "have" phrase needs to modify *buy*, not *jet*.

As for 3), it's fine. It sounds almost as good as "a space heater to dry my hair more naturally"

But 4) sounds contrived. It would be simpler, more straightforward and most natural to just leave out "having":

- For a lasting shine in your hair, {buy/get/use} ShineOn Shampoo.

Number 5) sounds non-idiomatic. The collocation "for having" is usually in such constructions as " thank you for having us over" or "I am thankful for having a roof over my head." in regard to future results, we might hear  "I plan *on having* a good time" or I plan *to have* a good time", not "I plan for having a good time". So I would phrase #5 as:

- We agreed to cooperate more, to have a better life together.

Comment: No. 5 has been changed so that the problem you mention is eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentences are grammatically ok.  However, I would personally use the infinitive in all of them, except maybe the first one.  Also, sentences 4 and 5 either wouldn't use *having*:

> For a lasting shine in your hair, buy ShineOn Shampoo.
>   My neighbor and I have decided to cooperate more for a better life together.

Or would use the infinitive:

> To have a lasting shine in your hair, buy ShineOn Shampoo.
>   My neighbor and I have decided to cooperate more to have a better life together.

*For* in these cases is answering the question "Why?"; "What for?" is an alternative to why.  The infinitive version is entirely acceptable as well.  For the most part, I find the infinitive form preferable to the for + verb-ing form.  When in doubt, use the infinitive, unless you omit the verb entirely as in my first two examples.

Answer (score 2):

Purpose can be expressed with the infinitive or a gerund.

Which to use, depends on what is the more natural sentence structure.

You examples may not technically break a rule, but they would sound more natural with an infinitive instead, except maybe 4.

When using "I" as the subject, the infinitive is better.

> I bought a plane to fly.
>   I bought a heater to dry my hair.

If you make the object the subject, the gerund is better.

> The plane was bought for flying. 
>   The space heater is for drying hair and not for warming the house.

Answer (score 0):

All those sentences seem **correct** to me, just some things may need to be improved.

---

> 1/  I have decided to purchase a jet for getting to NYC and back more quickly.

I would rather use *going to* than *getting to*

> 2/ I have decided to buy a jet for having a quicker way to get to NYC and back.

Maybe *"to buy a jet for having a quicker journey to go to NYC and back"*? I really don't like the *"to get to somewhere"*

Comment: I edited Sentence 5.

Comment: @pazzo It's ok for me ;)