# Shall I use gerund or infinitives with the verb "to apologize"?

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

Which of the two sentences is correct?

> I sent an email to apologize

or

> I sent an email for apologizing

Comment: Not sure of the exact grammatical reason, but 'to' is correct here.

Comment: You apologize *for* having done something or for neglecting to do something:  *I apologize for forgetting to wake you up.*

Comment: I think both *to* and *for* construction are acceptable generally. But in this case *for* construction doesn't sound good. Another thing, you have to include a recipient. I would prefer the *to* version in this case, but that is a personal choice - *"I sent him an email to apologize."* Or *"I sent him a letter of apology"*. Example with *for* construction - *"This is at this time I have sent him a letter for inviting in Reunion Island. "*

Comment: possible duplicate of ['I have decided to purchase a jet for getting to NYC and back more quickly.'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59468/i-have-decided-to-purchase-a-jet-for-getting-to-nyc-and-back-more-quickly)

Comment: The verb *apologize* doesn't determine the form here.

Answer (score 1):

These two are your best options

> I sent an email to apologize for (insert relevant circumstances)

or

> I sent an email apologizing for (insert relevant circumstances)

In the second example, you simply need to change the position of "apologizing" and "for"

Comment: I think the answer could be expanded beyond just apologize.  I can't think of a situation where "I sent an email for <gerund>" would work. "

Comment: I sent him an email for editing. Or for recommending.

Comment: I think the context will determine what construction we need to use.